# Can we show different browse layout for different collection in Dspace?

Tags: dspace

I have feedback collection in that i want to show the username  but in the same time in other collection i don't.

My question is on webui.itemlist.columns , here i have edited and added

dc.username
like this

webui.itemlist.columns = thumbnail, dc.date.issued(date), dc.title,
dc.contributor.author, dc.username

so here is my question, i have two collection one is feedback and another one
is working paper , and i dont want to show username column in feedback.but not in working paper
is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your theme and tune it for the working paper.
Then configure xmlui.xconf to use this theme for the working paper collection adding it to the theme list:

```
 <theme name="workingPaper" handle="123456789/1" path="theme1/"/>
 <theme name="general" regex=".*" path="theme2/"/>
```

Comment: Given the webui configuration properties, I think the question is about JSPUI. But it would be nice if the question made that clear.