# Ddspace 5.5 xmlui - different themes for different collections?

Tags: user-interface, themes, dspace

Is it possible to apply different themes to different collections within a single DSpace XMLUI instance? What would be the general procedure (any documentation?)?

This question is similar, but I think it refers to the JSPUI: [Can we show different browse layout for different collection in Dspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30342517/2376023)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To create a new theme, see the following page

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/XMLUI+Configuration+and+Customization#XMLUIConfigurationandCustomization-CreatingaNewTheme

#### If you using a Mirage2 (responsive) theme see

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Mirage+2+Configuration+and+Customization#Mirage2ConfigurationandCustomization-AdditionalDeveloperdocumentation

and

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/master/dspace-xmlui-mirage2#multiple-themes

### To assign themes to collections, see

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/XMLUI+Configuration+and+Customization#XMLUIConfigurationandCustomization-Themes

Comment: Thanks Terry - that's exactly the info I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to see how this works in practice, look at our institutional repository, which has twenty five different themes, all which inherit from one master theme (to maximize code reuse and minimize the maintenance burden):

- https://cgspace.cgiar.org/handle/10568/1
- https://cgspace.cgiar.org/handle/10568/3530

The code for these themes lives in `dspace/modules/xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/themes` in our public [source code repository](https://github.com/ilri/DSpace) and DSpace decides which theme to use in each community and or collection based on the logic in `dspace/config/xmlui.xconf`.

This method is valid for DSpace 4.x and 5.x, but hasn't been tested personally in DSpace 6.x. Our repository is currently running 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer provided by aorth.

The themes in the repository are all based on 1 parent theme, this to minimise duplication.

This is called "0_CGIAR" for the following reasons:

- The "child" themes import this theme in the xsl and css.
- In this version of DSpace, the themes are loaded alphabetically.
- It wasn't possible to load in the parent theme for "AfricaRising" for example if the parent theme was called "Base" or something like that, because it wasn't loaded yet.